# What's the best way to update items that belong to a collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Section model which has many SectionTests. Each SectionTest has a 'position' attribute.

I am creating a screen that allows the user to alter the position attribute for all the SectionTests in a Section.  So I'm updating a single attribute of a collection.

What is the best way of doing this in the routes and the controller?

Here is my current routes file :

```
resources :sections do
  resources :section_tests
end
```

My first thoughts are to do it in the 'edit' action of the 'section_tests' controller, but 'edit' is usually used to edit only the attributes of a single model.

Where would you put this code?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to update a section that is linked to a section_test? You could use an [Active Record Callback](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) like `after_save` in your SectionTest model.

Comment: No, I'm trying to update one of the columns in a collection of SectionTest models that are joined to the Section model via a has_many relationship.

Comment: [This](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select) might be what you are looking for. Your question is missing a lot of code to help give people an idea of what you want.